# io-ts to strict validate if object has no declared property

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

I'm using [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) to do input validation for an API. I need to ensure there has no un-declared property in the requirement object.

For example, if I define the interface of request as following:

```js
const Request = t.type({
  id: t.string,
  name: t.string
});
```

And if the input is as following:

```js
const req = { 
  id: 'r1',
  name: 'req 1',
  description: 'desc' // property "description" is not declaration on Request type.
}
```

and then I do validating as following:

```js
const r = Request.decode(req);

if (isLeft(r)) {
    console.log(PathReporter.report(r));
} else {
    console.log("validate success");
}
```

I expect output is an error for the un-declared property. but it is successed.

Have there any way to do the strict validation based on io-ts?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this question.
https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/issues/322#issuecomment-513170377

```js
import * as t from 'io-ts';
import { chain } from 'fp-ts/Either'
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function';

function getExcessProps(props: t.Props, r: Record<string, unknown>): string[] {
  const ex = []
  for (const k of Object.keys(r)) {
    if (!props.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      ex.push(k)
    }
  }
  return ex
}

export function excess<C extends t.InterfaceType<t.Props>>(codec: C): C {
  const r = new t.InterfaceType(
    codec.name,
    codec.is,
    (input, c) => pipe(
      t.UnknownRecord.validate(input, c),
      chain(result => {
        const ex = getExcessProps(codec.props, result)
        return ex.length > 0
          ? t.failure(
            input,
            c,
            `Invalid value ${JSON.stringify(input)} supplied to : ${
              codec.name
            }, excess properties: ${JSON.stringify(ex)}`
          )
          : codec.validate(input, c)
      })),
    codec.encode,
    codec.props
  )
  return r as C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly an answer to your question, but `io-ts` does also provide `strict` which will omit any properties from the input object that are not declared on the codec. (Whereas `type` will retain such additional properties.) `strict` is an alias of `exact(type(...))`.

Of course, this doesn't really help you with validation, but there may be related use-cases where being able to strip out additional properties is helpful.